# disable mouse click while processing/loading

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I got some "senior level code" that I do not understand right now. I have an issue with disabling a mouse click while function is running. Usually "processing mode" takes up to 30 seconds, So I want mouse click to be unavalable for user during this time. I have attached my code below and css. I have already tried to use `pointer-events: none;` but it is being applied only for an element, not for a full page.

please note: attached code is not executable, it is just a small component :)

```js
import React, { ReactElement, PureComponent } from "react";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter, skip } from "rxjs/operators";

import { IObjectMap, IRootProvider, RxUnwrap } from ":framework";

import { StickyMode } from ":WebGrid/metadata";
import { CheckReadonlyEditableConsole } from ":WebGrid/services/gridService/CheckReadonlyEditableConsole";

import { IDataCellProps } from "./IDataCellProps";
import { CellMode } from "./cellMode";
import { IDataCellManager } from "./iCellManager";

import "./GridDataGenericCell.styl";

/**
 * Generic data cell component
 */
export abstract class GridDataGenericCell<P extends IDataCellProps<TValue> = IDataCellProps, S = {}, TValue = any> extends PureComponent<P, S> implements IRootProvider {
  private static readonly ExtraPx = 2;
  public static defaultCellClass<P extends IDataCellProps>(props: P) { // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-shadow
    const currentMode = props.cellManager.getMode().getValue();
    const inChildRowClass = props.cellManager.isChildRow$.getValue() ? "in-child-row" : "";
    const conditionallyDisabled = props.cellManager.isEditable && !props.cellManager.editable$.getValue() ? "edit-disabled" : "";
    return `web-grid-cell web-grid-data-cell ${props.cellManager.columnName} ${currentMode}-mode ${inChildRowClass} ${conditionallyDisabled}`;
  }

  protected get styles() {
    if (!this.props.cellManager.width) {
      return {
        ...this.props.cellManager.style,
      };
    }

    let extraStyles: any;
    const currentMode = this.props.cellManager.getMode().getValue();
    if (currentMode === CellMode.edit && this.props.cellManager.isNearToStickBorder) {
      if (this.props.cellManager.stickyMode === StickyMode.Left) {
        extraStyles = { marginRight: `${GridDataGenericCell.ExtraPx}px` };
      }
    }

    return {
      ...this.props.cellManager.style,
      ...extraStyles,
    };
  }

  protected abstract root: HTMLElement | null;

  public getRoot<T = HTMLElement | null>(): T {
    return this.root as any;
  }

  private readonly renderersTable: IObjectMap<() => ReactElement<any> | null> = {
    [CellMode.view]: this.renderViewMode.bind(this),
    [CellMode.edit]: this.renderEditMode.bind(this),
    [CellMode.processing]: this.renderProcessingMode.bind(this),
    [CellMode.saving]: this.renderSavingMode.bind(this)
  };

  private valueSubscription?: Subscription;
  private editValueSubscription?: Subscription;
  private modeSubscription?: Subscription;
  private isChildRowSubscription?: Subscription;
  private bgColorSubscription?: Subscription;
  private isEditableSubscription?: Subscription;

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.subscribe(this.props.cellManager);
  }

  public componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  public componentWillReceiveProps(next: P) {
    if (next.cellManager !== this.props.cellManager) {
      this.subscribe(next.cellManager);
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  }

  public render() {
    const cm = this.props.cellManager;
    const currentMode = cm.getMode().getValue();
    const title$ = cm.editableMessage$;
    const renderer = this.renderersTable[currentMode];

    const element = renderer ? renderer() : null;
    return  (title$ && cm.isEditable && element) ? <RxUnwrap observable$={title$}>{title => title ? React.cloneElement(element, { title } as any) : element}</RxUnwrap> : element;
  }

  protected classLine(props: P) {
    return GridDataGenericCell.defaultCellClass(props);
  }

  /**
   * Render component on view mode
   */
  protected abstract renderViewMode(): JSX.Element;

  /**
   * Render component on edit mode
   */
  protected abstract renderEditMode(): JSX.Element | null;

  /**
   * Render component on saving mode
   */
  protected abstract renderSavingMode(): JSX.Element;

  protected renderProcessingMode(): JSX.Element | null {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(x) => this.root = x}
        style={this.styles}
        className={this.classLine(this.props)}
      >
        <span className="value">Processing...</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  protected throwIfValueUndefined(value?: TValue) {
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Value of column ${this.props.cellManager.columnName} is undefined`);
    }

    return value as TValue;
  }

  protected subscribe(cellManager: IDataCellManager<TValue>) {
    this.unsubscribe();

    const update = () => this.forceUpdate();

    this.editValueSubscription = cellManager.getEditValue()
      .pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe(update);

    this.modeSubscription = cellManager.getMode()
      .pipe(
        skip(1),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(update);

    this.valueSubscription = cellManager.getValue()
      .pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe(update);

    this.isChildRowSubscription = cellManager.isChildRow$
      .pipe(
        skip(1),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(update);

    this.bgColorSubscription = cellManager.backgroundColor$ && cellManager.backgroundColor$
      .pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe(update);

    this.isEditableSubscription = cellManager.editable$ && cellManager.editable$
      .pipe(
        skip(1),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        filter(() => cellManager.editableMessage$.getValue() !== CheckReadonlyEditableConsole.EmptyEditableMessage), // to prevent updates in TOM mode
      )
      .subscribe(update);
  }

  protected unsubscribe() {
    this.editValueSubscription && this.editValueSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.modeSubscription && this.modeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.valueSubscription && this.valueSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.isChildRowSubscription && this.isChildRowSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.bgColorSubscription && this.bgColorSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.isEditableSubscription && this.isEditableSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```css
@import "../../../../../Applications/Layout/styles/variables.styl";
@import "../../../../variables.styl";

.web-grid-data-cell
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height 100%;
  color: $grid-font-color;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $cell-border-color;
  &.view-mode,
  &.saving-mode
    .hoverable-element
      height: 100%;
      .full-element
        padding: $cell-padding;
  &.view-mode,
  &.processing-mode,
  &.saving-mode
    padding: $cell-padding;
  &.processing-mode,
  &.saving-mode
    background-color: $cell-saving-processing-bg;
  &.processing-mode
    .value
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height 100%;
  &.in-child-row
    background-color: gray-color-8;
  &.edit-disabled:hover
    cursor: not-allowed;
  &.edit-mode
    z-index: $web-grid-data-cell-edit-mode-zindex;
    .multiline-text
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      textarea
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(92, 105, 122, 0.8);
        border: 0;
```

Comment: You should add where you have that button in your question too

Comment: oh, true, will find where it is written(it is editable table cell) @NickVu